# Netbeans git Diff I can see the changes but I can not modify them

Tags: git, netbeans

I am working with netbeans and the integrated GIT in there. I have made a pull and merged the branches. When I want to push it says :

remote repository contains commits unmerged into the local branch

I then open the diff tool which does show what the differences are but the buttons for 'revert modifications' or 'commit changes' are disabled as well as the ones for 'changes between head and working tree' 'changes between HEAD and index' and changes between index and working tree.

Most of the changes are ones that don't really affect what I did so I just want to approve them. But I can't seem to find how or were.

Comment: I fixed it. I used git bash to pull from the remote, and then I used netbeans git to resolve conflicts. That way I finally could choose what changes I wanted to keep. After that I had to commit my merge and pushed it to the remote.

Comment: But it still doesn't resolve NetBeans problem with git - it's driving me crazy